# Create custom button based on Android style

Tags: android, button, styles

I need to create a custom button control that will inherit from the same Android style as all other buttons in my application. However, I want to be able to add several lines of text where some characters of the text will be in different colors. Is there anyway to achieve this, I can't seem to see a way?

Currently I have created a view that looks like a button by drawing the background, this is ok but I want the background etc to change with the application style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your button descend from the generic theme for [`Widget.Button`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#L314). This way you can ensure that all the default settings will come through for you.